# How do I show the PE headers in IDA pro?

Tags: portable-executable, ida

I distinctly remember, at some point, being able to expand the PE header and look at everything stored in it on IDA, however when I look at it now it just shows some basic information from the headers and then immediately goes into the first section. I specifically remember being able to expand the section headers and view information like the size of each header, their relative virtual address, et cetera.  How can I do this?

As it is now I cant even go back far enough in the hex view to see the headers, the hex view stops at the beginning of the text section.

Answer (score 6):

When opening your executable, select the "Manual load" checkbox:

[image]

...then confirm the dialog asking to "Load the file header?":

[image]

All PE headers will then be visible (e.g. Optional-Header) ...

[image]